# MySQL 8.0.13: Default Value as uuid not working

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I am trying to set the Default value as UUID() in MySQL version 8.0.13. But upon successful execution, the default value resets to NOT NULL.

MySQL version:

[image: "version script"]

Here is my CREATE TABLE script

```sql
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE)),
  `start_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `end_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

the log output on table generation, 
`SQL script was successfully applied to the database.`

The TABLE definition post execution:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `start_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `end_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I am not able to figure out why this could happen when documentation clearly mentions that parenthesis enclosed functions are allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug with default expressions for primary key columns, [Expression Default is made NULL during CREATE TABLE query, if field is made PK](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94668).

It is fixed in [MySQL 8.0.19](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html):

> For a column defined as a PRIMARY KEY in a CREATE TABLE statement, a default value given as an expression was ignored. (Bug #29596969, Bug #94668)

As a workaround (if you cannot upgrade), you can add the primary key afterwards with an `ALTER TABLE`-statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE)),
  `start_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL, 
  `end_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE `session` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

Comment: I tested on a Docker container of 8.0.18 and it works.

Comment: @Madeo Default expressions require at least MySQL 8, so you probably have an older version. (And the original question isn't about that expression throwing an error, the question is about the syntax being ok (in MySQL 8), but then MySQL ignoring that expression when making the table. If you need help with a different problem, e.g. getting uuids to work in MySQL 5.7 or similar, you should ask or find such a question).

Comment: @Madeo Ok, i was not precise enough: default expressions requires at least MySQL 8.0.13. Nevertheless, the original question assumes the syntax to be fine (e.g. no syntax error), but the resulting table to be broken. If you have a different problem, you should asked it in a different question (well, unless it is already answered by the verison conflict), as here, it is unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

I needed the column to not be a binary one. So, in my case, I declared it like this:

```
`id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID()),
```

For anyone who needs it to store UUIDs with default values in a char column.

Comment: LOL, this solved it for me. Note that `DEFAULT UUID()` is not working, you need the extra parentheses `DEFAULT (UUID())`, but you don't need it when eg.: `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`